# Webmin not responding on CentOS

Tags: centos

I've been using Webmin on CentOS for a couple of weeks now. Everything was going well until I tried to login today and it wouldn't load the page.

I've tried restarting the service and checked the `miniserv.error` file (lots of `Failed to initialize SSL connection` but they seem to be all over the log before it stopped working ).

Just tried reinstalling, still can't connect.

Is there anything else I should test?

Comment: Do you use http or https?

Comment: https , but they're both not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebooting cent os solved the problem .

Comment: Glad you resolved the issue.  Please be sure to mark your answer as "accepted" when you are able.

Comment: Apologies, forgot all about it.