# Why can not I connect to Webmin on my AWS centOS server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, centos7, webmin

I have a centOS server on AWS and I can not connect to Webmin.
I followed the installation steps that (shows this page), but when I click on the link that is generated after completing the installation of Webmin, the following error appears:
This website can not be accessed The IP address of the server xxxxxxxxxxx could not be found.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN
I have read [other responses:](https://serverfault.com/questions/354794/webmin-not-responding-on-centos) ()

I have searched for a solution by Google for three days without success.
On the server I have enabled ports 10000, 22, 21, 20
I do not know what else I can do or where to go.
I may not show you enough details of my problem so you can help me, but it's the first time on this site that I read the rules.
If I have to add more details, please tell me what I can do so they can help me.
I also use a translator to ask the question, which can cause errors.
Can you help me connect Webmin to my server?
Thank you

Comment: You're trying to use a hostname or domain name that doesn't exist. Google "how to add a host entry to /etc/hosts".

Comment: Thanks @JennyD I think that is not the error, since I use the server IP and this is correct.

Comment: You quoted an error message saying *The IP address of the server xxxxxxxxxxx could not be found. DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN*. That message does not come up if you're connecting to the server IP - it only comes up if you are connecting to a hostname which cannot be resolved because the domain doesn't exist. You have misunderstood something here.